# can i use multiple queries in using single mysqlconnection in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, database, c#-6.0

```
public static void InitializeUsers(MySqlConnection cn, List<MarketingExecutive> marketingExecutives, List<FieldOfficer> fieldOfficers)
        {

            cn.Open();
            MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("select * from loanrequestprocessing_db.tbl_users where TypeOfUser='Marketing Executive'",cn);

            MySqlDataReader reader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                MarketingExecutive M = new MarketingExecutive()
                {
                    ExecutiveId = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]),
                    ExecutiveName = Convert.ToString( reader[1]),
                    Area = Convert.ToString(reader[3]),
                    Address = Convert.ToString(reader[4])



                };


                marketingExecutives.Add(M);
            }
            reader.Close();
            MySqlCommand SelectCommand2 = new MySqlCommand("select * from loanrequestprocessing_db.tbl_users where TypeOfUser='Field Officer'", cn);

            MySqlDataReader reader2 = SelectCommand2.ExecuteReader();
            while(reader2.Read())
            {
                FieldOfficer f = new FieldOfficer()
                {
                    OfficerId = Convert.ToInt32(reader2[0]),
                    OfficerName = Convert.ToString(reader2[1]),
                    Area = Convert.ToString(reader2[3]),
                    Address = Convert.ToString(reader2[4])

                };
                fieldOfficers.Add(f);
            }
            reader2.Close();

            cn.Close();


        }
```

In above Method I have used single connection with multiple readers in same connection keeping in mind only one reader is opened at a time still i m getting error what is wrong with my code any help will be welcome  i am new to c#

Comment: what error you are getting please specify

Comment: List is not getting filled at run time

Comment: can you initialize your list 
List<MarketingExecutive> marketingExecutives = new List<MarketingExecutive>();
List<FieldOfficer> fieldOfficers = new List<FieldOfficer>()

Comment: I am getting initialized Lists for both lists to the function

Comment: @AshwinDivekar : have you tried initializing the List ? and you are getting runtime exception ?

Comment: @Chintan I am passing initialized lists to function and its not exception lists are not getting filled

Comment: have you debugged that are you getting data from DataReader?

Comment: Put this code inside try catch block . you  can catch error quickly

Comment: can there be a problem with refernce of lists not getting passed back to calling method hence they are empty in calling method and not in current method

Comment: are the lists getting filled in InitializeUsers method ?

Comment: yes they are getting filled in initializeUsers menthod

Comment: yes then in the calling method it should receive the updated lists so you need to return the updated lists from InitializeUsers

Comment: Ok I will check And update

Comment: Tests For This is failing saying 
Initialize Users:Check For Users Are Not Null 0.0 4.0    
 Initialize Users:Check For All Marketing Executives Are Loaded 0.0 6.0  
Initialize Users:Check For All Field Officers Are Loaded 0.0 6.0  
 Initialize Users:Check For Number Of Item Currect Count 0.0 4.0

Comment: can you send me sample code i will try to execute

Comment: http://collabedit.com/9vdva

Comment: In Main 
add following line
LoanRequests = InitializeLoanRequests(MyConn, LoanRequests);

Change function InitializeLoanRequests to
public static List<LoanRequest> InitializeLoanRequests(MySqlConnection cn, List<LoanRequest> loanRequests)

and return return loanRequests;

you will get Update LoanRequests

Comment: what about InitializeUsers??

Comment: yes for InitializeUsers(MyConn, ListOfMarketExec, ListOfFieldOff) on Main
change to InitializeUsers(MyConn, out ListOfMarketExec, out ListOfFieldOff);

and change function to public static void InitializeUsers(MySqlConnection cn,out List<MarketingExecutive> marketingExecutives,out List<FieldOfficer> fieldOfficers)
that will give you updated data

Comment: I will try and update

Comment: @AshwinDivekar :the changes worked?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

It is better to use "using" to open a connection and write two queries in this     connection.

```
using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection (connectionString))
  {
      connection.Open();

      // write codes here

 }
```

Comment: @Wintergeen Can you please explain why my approach is failing i am not getting that

Comment: I am passing initialized lists to function and its not exception lists are not getting filled –